# Are there problems on tor netowrk?

Tags: speed, dos

I have speed problems on tor with tails. I mean the browsing is very very slow. For example my usual bandwidth is 5,3 **mbit** and on tor network is 88 **kbit**. Some guy on #tor@oftc.net are saying that there is an attack (ddos) to some relay... is that true ? all outhere have speed problems on tor ? or it is just me ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Some guy on #tor@oftc.net are saying that there is an attack (ddos) to some relay... is that true ?

Not for all relays, at least (I operate one). There are around [6000-7000 relays](https://metrics.torproject.org/networksize.html), its unlikely any attacker would be able to siginificantly impact the entire Tor network at once.

Beyond that, I've experienced no speed losses myself so even if one could, they're not currently.

You should investigate this locally, try pluggable transports like `obfs4` or `meek` with [bridges](https://bridges.torproject.org/) to ensure your ISP isn't throttling Tor connection speeds.

Comment: Is there a particularly good graph on the metrics site to see if Tor is under an active attack?

Answer (score 0):

You may check here with some tools:

https://metrics.torproject.org